# Trying to put two runat=server forms in one web form asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, forms, webforms, runatserver

i'm building a site for course project in Web forms asp.net
and i did a master page for all the website
i want to have a text box that acts as a search in the website
but it needs to be in

```
<form runat="server">
```

this is master code

```
<html>
    <div id="topContent">
        <head runat="server">
            <form runat="server">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                <title>Dor Lugasi Guitar Shop</title>
                <link href="Styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                <right>
                <img src="../Images/logobk2.png" alt="Powered by DLG!" class="auto-style7"/><br />
                <center id="headdiv">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkHome" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Pages/Home.aspx" >Home</asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkLogin" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Pages/Login.aspx">Login</asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkContact" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Pages/Contact.aspx" >Contact</asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkGuitarLab" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Pages/GuitarLab.aspx">Guitar Lab</asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:ImageButton style="float:left;margin-left:10px;" ID="btnCart" runat="server" Height="55px" ImageUrl="~/Images/cart.png" Width="55px" PostBackUrl="~/Pages/Cart.aspx" />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" BackColor="Silver" BorderColor="Black" TextMode="Search" placeholder="               Search" onkeypress="txtSearch"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSearch" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/src.png" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" Width="25px" />
                </center>
                <center id="headdiv" class="auto-style6">
                    <asp:Label style="float:left;margin-left:10px;" ID="lblLoggedUser" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnLogOut" runat="server" OnClick="btnLogOut_Click" Visible="False" CssClass="auto-style5" Height="24px" Width="99px">Log Out</asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:LinkButton style="float:right;margin-right:10px;" ID="lnkManageProducts" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Pages/ManageProducts.aspx">Manage Products</asp:LinkButton>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:LinkButton style="float:right;margin-right:10px;" ID="lnkManageUsers" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Pages/ManageUsers.aspx">Manage Users</asp:LinkButton>
                </center>
            </form>
        </head>
    </div>
    <body id="body">
        <form runat="server">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <center>
                <asp:contentplaceholder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
                </asp:contentplaceholder>
            </center>
            <footer id="footer" class="auto-style3">
                </left>
                <img src="../Images/logowhite.png" alt="Powered by ASP.NET!" />
            </footer>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

but im getting a:

```
A page can have only one server-side Form tag.
```

before i added this  search textbox and button i had

```
<form runat="server">
<html>
...
<head>.....</head>
<body>....</body>
<footer>.....</footer>

</html>
</form>
```

and it worked 
but at the login page when i pressed Enter it applied to the search form instead of the login form

Comment: You got to wire it up to another "page". A `search.aspx` page that your code behind handles. Here's an example I found: http://www.frederikvig.com/2009/06/using-multiple-forms-on-an-asp-net-web-forms-page/

Answer (score 2):

eventually i ended up making a single form for the page and just put the  specific form that had buttons in

```
<asp:Panel ID="search_panel" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSearch">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" BackColor="Silver" BorderColor="Black" TextMode="Search" placeholder="               Search" onkeypress="txtSearch"></asp:TextBox>     
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSearch" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/src.png" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" Width="25px" />                     
                    </asp:Panel>
```

i hope thats the right way

Comment: Yes, in Web Forms, just like the error message indicates, you can only have one form with the `runat=server` attribute. It's dumb, but that's Web Forms. Did you choose to use Web Forms, or were you forced to? If your teacher is still teaching Web Forms in 2017, then they need to get with the times and teach modern web tooling. At least ASP.NET MVC, but it'd be even better to teach a front end system like Angular, Vue, React etc and combine that with a REST based API framework like ASP.NET Web API.

Comment: i totally agree with you.
in my spare time im teaching myself angular
but the point of the course is not the site building, communication and the site is just  to implement the basic stuff